# How can I track all of my Box2D collisions in a clean, manageable manner?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d, collision-detection

I am using Box2D for the first time seriously in a medium sized Flash Game that I am working on. My current experience with Box2D is limited to creating a world, bodies and adding those bodies to the world in a functional manner.

I'm finding it easy enough to integrate Box2D into my game environment, maintaining well-written code and have completed a few tutorials that walk through dealing with collisions. The issue that I'm facing now is that my game will have many bodies, each interacting with other bodies in different ways, and I'm finding it hard to write my own `b2ContactListener` subclass without it getting extremely messy.

Based off a tutorial I used, I have created my own subclass of `b2ContactListener` and added an override of the `BeginContact()` method. The argument that `BeginContact()` receives when it is called will reference an instance of `b2Contact`, through which I can access two `b2Fixture` instances (the two instances that have collided). I am then able to access the `b2Body` instance associated with each of those `b2Fixture`s.

- **Problem:** Currently I have a roundabout way of finding out what two things collided (i.e. whether they're a wall and a missile, or the player and a tree, etc) which uses `GetUserData()` and looks like this as an example:

  ```
  var f1Player:Boolean = contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData() is Player
  var f2Player:Boolean = contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetUserData() is Player
  var f1Tree:Boolean = contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData() is Tree
  var f2Tree:Boolean = contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetUserData() is Tree
  // ... continutes with all possible combinations.


  // Example of managing a collision:
  if(f1Player && f2Tree)
  {
      // Player (FixtureA) and Tree (FixtureB)
  }

  if(f2Player && f1Tree)
  {
      // Player (FixtureB) and Tree (FixtureA)
  }
  ```

  As you can see, this is going to end up extremely long and unmanageable. I also have to write each set of actions to perform twice to cater for a certain element being FixtureA or FixtureB, or vice versa (obviously in the form of a function call with the parameters swapped around rather than literally re-written).

This is clearly not the correct approach, but I haven't been able to locate resources that more thoroughly explain collision detection management.

Does anyone have experience with collision detection management using Box2D that they can share? Also, is using `SetUserData( entityThatOwnsTheBody );` the correct way to be using that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with something much nicer than the original.

Firstly, I just have my `Being` class (which owns a `b2Body`) set itself as its bodies' `UserData`. This class will also contain an `onContact()` method and look similar to the below:

```
public class Being
{

    private var _body:b2Body;


    public function Being()
    {
        // Define the body here.
        // ...

        _body.SetUserData(this);
    }


    public function onCollision(being:Being = null):void
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Then in my own `b2ContactListener` implementation, I simply pass the colliding `Being` (or null, if there is no `Being` assigned to the colliding `b2Body`'s `UserData`) to the opposing `Being`'s `onCollision()`:

```
override public function BeginContact(contact:b2Contact):void
{
    var bodyA:b2Body = contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody();
    var bodyB:b2Body = contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody();

    var beingA:Being = bodyA.GetUserData() as Being || null;
    var beingB:Being = bodyB.GetUserData() as Being || null;

    beingA && beingA.onCollision(beingB);
    beingB && beingB.onCollision(beingA);
}
```

And finally in each of my subclasses of `Being`, I can easily prepare logic appropriate for a collision between other `Being`s of a certain type:

```
class Zombie extends Being
{
    override public function onCollision(being:Being = null):void
    {
        if(being && being is Bullet)
        {
            // Damage this Zombie and remove the bullet.
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the long 'if' statement just gets moved into the Being class. How about for processing that should only be done once for the collision, eg. playing a sound or incrementing a score.

Comment: @iforce2d That's true, I mean there is going to have to be the `if()` statements either way to add criteria for each collision combination, but this seems more organized than having everything in one file. It provides me with the ability to easily locate a collision between two things via the relevant classes and I don't have to check which Being is which for every collision manually.

Comment: As for single occurences, that can be managed by the individual as well by having a simple `hasBeenTouched` boolean or similar.

Comment: Depending on what should happen when things touch you might actually need a list rather than a boolean, unless it is only possible for each thing to only touch at most one other thing per timestep.

Comment: @iforce2d I believe the `BeginContact()` method fires separately for each collision, but I'm not that experienced with Box2D yet so let me know if that's not the case :)

Comment: That's correct. But there may be many collisions in one time step. I guess for most games it will not be an issue, and I am being somewhat pedantic - sorry :)

Comment: @iforce2d No need for apology, any information I can get is great.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's a bit of a nuisance indeed. Actually I think the way you have it is quite typical.

fwiw Box2D itself has to deal with a similar problem when testing whether fixtures overlap. There are a bunch of functions such as b2CollideCircles, b2CollidePolygonAndCircle, b2CollidePolygons etc, and when two fixtures come near each other the engine chooses which of these functions should be used.

It does this by putting the function pointers in a 2-dimensional array, then looks up the appropriate function in this array by using the two shape types as index. See the first three functions in b2Contact.cpp for details.

Of course, if you can't pass around function references like this in AS3 then I guess this answer doesn't help much, but I thought I would post anyway as C/C++/JS users might come by.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `c++` version of `Box2d`, but I think the same approach will work in actionscript.  I create a class `Object`, that contain a `b2Body *_body` pointer and a pointer to graphical representation. `_body`'s `UserData` was set to point to `Object *`. class `Object` had the following methods:

```
virtual bool acceptsContacts    ();
virtual void onContactBegin     (const ContactData &data);
virtual void onContactEnded     (const ContactData &data);
virtual void onContactPreSolve  (const ContactData &data);
virtual void onContactPostSolve (const ContactData &data);
```

When collision was detected in `b2ContactListener` subclass, it checked if collided bodies have user data. If so, it casted their user data to `Object*` and if any of the collided objects accepted contacts - it created `ContactData` ( a class with all required information about collision) and put it in it's internal `list` to deliver later.

When `b2World::update` method returned, `ContactListener` delivers all contact information to objects to process. Delivery was delayed in order you could create new bodies, joints and so on, right when processing collision (which is not allowed while update is executing)

Also you must notify `ContactListener` (just put a pointer to it inside `ContactData`) if one of the collided body was deleted during collision processing, so it can invalidate appropriate contacts and not deliver them